# Create dynamic html table, where td values associate to th values from ms sql db

Tags: jquery, sql-server, coldfusion

Using ColdFusion 9 server and MS-SQL db, I am trying to create html table, where td values associate to th values from the same MS-Sql db table.
**Query 1 - get departments:**

```
<cfquery datasource="datasrc" name="qGetDep">
    SELECT DISTINCT Dept
    FROM someTable
    WHERE isnull(Dept, '') != ''
    ORDER BY DEPT ASC
</cfquery>
```

**Query 2 - get names**

```
<cfquery datasource="datasrc" name="qGetNam">
    SELECT a.Dept, a.names
    FROM someTable as a
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT Dept, MIN(ID) as ID, names
    FROM someTable
    GROUP BY Dept, names
    ) as b
    ON a.Dept = b.Dept
    AND a.ID = b.ID
    WHERE isnull(a.Dept, '') != ''
    ORDER BY a.Dept ASC
</cfquery>
```

**index.cfm**

```
<table border="1" id="table1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <cfoutput query="qGetDep">
                <th><b>#DEPT#</b></th>
            </cfoutput>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <cfoutput query="qGetNam">
            <tr>
                <cfloop query="qGetDep">
                    <cfset cls= qGetDep.Dept>
                    <cfif qGetNam.Dept EQ cls >
                        <td class="#cls#">#qGetNam.names#</td>
                    <cfelse>
                        <td class="#cls#"></td>
                    </cfif>

                </cfloop>
            </tr>
        </cfoutput>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**With my current data in db, this will output table similar to this:**
[image]

What I need it to be like this.
[image]

jQuery solution is acceptable.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have your second query in a loop?

Comment: Thank you for noticing, I just have removed that tag. One of my fail attempts, in  my second query I used WHERE a.Dept Like '#qGetDep.Dept#', but even removing that loop still outputs the same table format.

Comment: This being sql server, have you considered running a pivot query?

Comment: I have, and for some reason I can't figure out, it gives me only one row records.`SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @paramList + ' FROM(SELECT names, Dept FROM someTable )src PIVOT (MIN(name) FOR Dept IN (' + @paramList + ')) pvt'`

Comment: paramlist?  Your coldfusion queries don't appear to have any variables.

Comment: Well, assuming that I already declared @paramList in the query `DECLARE @paramList VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @paramList = STUFF((
 SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + Dept + ']'
 FROM someTable 
 WHERE isnull(Dept, '') != '' 
 FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'')`

Comment: Can you post a sample of the CFQUERY dump?

Comment: Actual data is private so I can not expose, but fake cfdump query sample qGetNam will be similar as 51Dept502 - Johns S, 53Dept510 - Dave H, 57Dept525 - Michael B, 57Dept525 - Steve S, 59Dept557 - Bob A, 59Dept557 - Jack A. So, each department can have many user names assigned to it.

Comment: @crashtestxxx what is the ID value in someTable a, someTable b ? Arey they ID for the departments?

Comment: @Sanjeev each row in db contains ID, department, name and more other information. So, what I need is group all by department, and output it in table, where department is the header, and names should go in the columns for their department where they associated to. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this based on my assumptions about you 'actual private data'.

**Hope even my assumption is wrong, this might put you in a proper direction.**

If this is your -

> Department Table

[image: Department Table]

and this is your

> People table

[image: People Table]

then using this query -

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT a.id AS pid
              ,a.NAME
              ,b.dept
          FROM deptPeople a
              ,deptTable b
         WHERE a.dept = b.dept
       ) AS A
  PIVOT(
        MIN(NAME) FOR dept IN ( dept1, dept2, dept3, dept4, dept5)
       ) AS B
```

will give you

[image: Final Result]

Combined everything in ColdFusion like this -

```
<cfquery datasource="que_tempdb_int" name="qGetDep">
    SELECT dept
    FROM deptTable
    ORDER BY DEPT ASC
</cfquery>

<cfset allDept = valuelist(qGetDep.dept,',') />

<cfquery name="qGetNam" datasource="que_tempdb_int">
    SELECT *
      FROM (
            SELECT a.id AS pid
                  ,a.NAME
                  ,b.dept
                  FROM deptPeople a
                  ,deptTable b
             WHERE a.dept = b.dept
           ) AS A
      PIVOT(
            MIN(NAME) FOR dept IN (#allDept#)
           ) AS B
</cfquery>

<table border="1" id="table1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <cfoutput query="qGetDep">
                <th><b>#DEPT#</b></th>
            </cfoutput>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <cfoutput query="qGetNam">
        <tr>
            <cfloop list="#allDept#" index="dept" delimiters=",">
            <td>#qGetNam[dept][qGetNam.currentRow]#</td>
            </cfloop>
        </tr>
    </cfoutput>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Final Result -

[image: HTML Pivot Table]